# OperationError at /teams/

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a database file I downloaded online and i am trying to get the contents from that database and display it on a template.

Here is the code from my view. "getAllTeams()" is the call to a method that connects to the database and gets the contents and returns a list

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from myTest.models import *
import pdb
import myTest.models
databaseFile ="../database.sqlite"

def index(request):
   return render(request,'myTest/home.html')

def teams(request):
   teamsList = getAllTeams(databaseFile)
   teamsList.sort(key= lambda t: t.team_name)
   # print(teamsList)
   context = {
        'teamsList':teamsList,
    }
    return render(request,'myTest/teams.html',context)
```

Here is the method that gets the data and returns a list of objects

```
  def getAllTeams(databaseFile):
    conn = create_connection(databaseFile)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Team t, Team_Attributes ta where 
    t.team_api_id = ta.team_api_id GROUP BY team_long_name")

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    teamList = []
    for row in rows:
        team = Team(row[0], row[1], row[2],
                    row[3], row[4], row[5],
                    row[6], row[7], row[8],
                    row[9], row[10], row[11],
                    row[12], row[13],
                    row[14], row[15], row[16],
                    row[17], row[18], row[19],
                    row[20], row[21], row[22],
                    row[23], row[24],
                    row[25], row[26], row[27])
        #print(team)
        teamList.append(team)
   return teamList
```

[This is the error I get when running the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFB6E.png)

[When I run the view in the console, the function works and returns the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRcZ0.png)

Comment: Well the error is clear. Are you sure that both runs connect to the *same* database?

Comment: Sure. When I run it on the console I just remove the request param and display the context. The file path is not touched

Comment: Why are you using a standalone connection and raw SQL with Django? Half the point of Django is that it manages all this for you.

Comment: Im using an external database file that has all the data I need. For this reason I dont need to use django to create models.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the settings file and under the databases settings I changed the name of the database from the default which was 'db.sqlite3' to 'database.sqlite' which is the name of the external database file I'm using.